# How large must be my raster for rasterizing a shapefile in R in a scale 1:100.000?

Tags: raster, r, gdal-rasterize

I´m trying to rasterize a shapefile of land cover for the colombian coast. The original shapefile is in a scale of 1:100000. I´m using this code in R language.

```
costa <- readOGR(file.choose()) #Here, I put the original shape
r <- raster(ncol=900000, nrow=900000) #This is the line in which I have problems. How big should be my raster for not losing too much information?
extent(r) <- extent(costa)
rcosta <- rasterize(costa, r)
```

Comment: What is "too much information"? That is up to you to decide.

Comment: start at 1000x1000 and go up until you like the answer or run out of memory

Comment: A scale of 1:100000 (or anything) doesn't make any sense for digital data. It means 1 unit on the map is 100000 units in the real world, which is fine for maps fixed on paper. But digital map data can be displayed at any scale - you can zoom in until your display is 1:1 scale if you want.